# How do I install curl in php5?

Tags: php

I currently have PHP 5.3 installed with Apache in 10.04 Lucid. How can I add the PHP Curl libraries? Do I need to install any other dependencies for curl?

Comment: I wonder why there is no answer showing how to compile the extension when you want a custom version.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

I believe that the package php5-curl should do the trick.  Use the package manager of your choice and the deps should be taken care of.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

You will need to restart the server afterwards:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Alternatively, if you are using php-fpm, you'll need to restart php5-fpm instead

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine asking here, but next time make sure to search the Software Center to save you some time ;)

Comment: This is on a server I'm managing from the CLI, what is the Software Center?

Comment: @DarrenNewton The CLI equivalent would probably `apt-cache search` btw.

Comment: @xav0989, it seems like this is a bug upstream, as on Debian it only reloads apache's config. It should restart apache.

Comment: debian info: on Debian 6 I didnt need to restart, installation just reloaded conf itself, and curl was working fine :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04
$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl

Answer (score 12):

For the subversion php5.6 use the following command (tested for Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5.6
php — version
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```

Comment: That will be for 16.04 and above?

Comment: Only tested it on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: With a PPA? There's no such package in the Ubuntu repos: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&keywords=php5.6-curl

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: works for 22.04. :o

Answer (score 7):

My conf: Ubuntu 11.10, already installed mysql,php5 and apache2, before installing php5-curl in terminal I did:

edit sources list like:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

you can check your configuration in http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Next command:

```
apt-get install aptitude
```

Next command:

```
aptitude install php5-curl
```

You get something like this:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
php5-curl{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.1 kB of archives. After unpacking 127 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-curl: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1) but 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     php5-curl [Not Installed]                          

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

**Your answer here is n**

Next lines print out:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Downgrade the following packages:                                             
1)     libapache2-mod-php5 [5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8 (now) -> 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1 (oneiric)]
2)     php5 [5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8 (now) -> 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1 (oneiric)]               
3)     php5-cli [5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8 (now) -> 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1 (oneiric)]           
4)     php5-common [5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8 (now) -> 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1 (oneiric)]        
5)     php5-gd [5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8 (now) -> 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1 (oneiric)]            
6)     php5-mysql [5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8 (now) -> 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1 (oneiric)]         

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
```

**Your answer here is y.**

In your browser open phpinfo(), check property:

```
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
```

In that folder you should now have **curl.so**

Edit php.ini

```
nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

find "dynamic extensions" add code below:

```
extension=curl.so
```

After that restart apache2 and check phpinfo(), curl must be enabled

Answer (score 5):

full solution for install LAMP and cURL extension:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

and then:

```
cd /etc/php5/apache2/

sudo nano php.ini
```

add this command: `extension=curl.so`

the last thing `restart` apache

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the php5-curl package.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 2):

Run following command

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-mcrypt php5-curl
```

Comment: What does `php5-mcrypt` have with this?

Answer (score 1):

For **php 5.6** this will do the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl

sudo service apache2 restart
```