# PHP - How to install php-curl without downgrading PHP version

Tags: php, versions, curl

I'm trying to install the php5-curl package, but I'm getting the dependency error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-curl : Depends: phpapi-20090626
             Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11) but 5.5.5+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have found [this guide here on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/195122/91448), but I'm afraid that will downgrade my php installation to an older version, which I don't want.

This is the PHP version I have installed:

```
tomica@as5830tg-elementary:~/Documents/apktool$ php --version
PHP 5.5.5-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2013 12:57:03) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

Is there any way for me to keep the PHP 5.5.5-1 and still install php-curl?

Comment: File a bug report against php-curl and have the dependencies resolved by the package maintainer.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that's a good idea. Do you have any advice how I should file a bug report for php-curl?

Comment: You file a bug report on launchpad - https://bugs.launchpad.net/

Comment: I have been using [ppa:ondrej/php5](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) for PHP.  This PPA includes `php5-curl`: `php --version` output: `PHP 5.5.12-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli)`. In case you aren't aware, adding the PPA will update all PHP packages installed on your system to the latest in the PPA, assuming the PPA has a more recent version. Best performed on a test machine.

Comment: @Paul your advice worked for me. Thanks a lot. Would you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using [ppa:ondrej/php5](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) for PHP. This PPA includes `php5-curl` and FYI:

`$ php --version`

`PHP 5.5.12-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli)`

In case you aren't aware, adding the PPA will update all PHP packages installed on your system to the latest in the PPA, assuming the PPA has a more recent version. Best performed on a test machine.

If you are like me, you research who the owners and contributors of PPAs are. The owner and, so far, sole contributor to this PPA has a very high karma on Launchpad, regularly updates the PPAs he manages, and googling his email address reveals he is very active on a number of FOSS projects. As of the time of this answer, I consider the PPA reliable.

Comment: Thanks again @Paul. I know of that repository, I've been using it before. But apparently for some reason I forgot to add it since my last OS installation. Added, updated, upgraded, installed php5-curl with no problem.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ Awesome! I just added his Postfix repository to my test server. I can't report yet that it's great for that (though I suspect it is), but that's really due to the fact that I'm completely re-configuring my mail server.